# How To make a preloader page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to have a page that preloads untill the contents of the link/page that is being visited is fully loaded.

here is my code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "pages/main.html",
    success: function(content)
    {
        $('#contentarea').html (content);
    }
});
    });



$('.menu_nav') .click (function () {
var href = $(this) .attr('href');
$('#contentarea').hide() .load(href).slideDown( 'very slow' )

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$(document).ajaxStart().ajaxStop()`:

```
 $(document).ajaxStart(function (){
     $('#contentarea').prev().append('<span>loading</span>');
 }).ajaxStop(function (){
    $('#contentarea').prev('span').remove();
 });
```

Comment: so I replace span in the append with the loading gif that I have?

Comment: Is there a way to time it?

Answer (score 0):

> **css**

```
#loader-wrapper{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   z-index: 10000;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

> **html**.put this div tag below the start of the body tag

```
<div id="loader-wrapper"></div>
```

> **javascript**

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var load_screen = document.getElementById("loader-wrapper");
  document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
```